# Sql Server - how to get last server restart (DMV reset date/time)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, dmv

I'm using some modifications to Glenn Berry's excellent DMV queries!

However, I would like to add to the resultset the 'last server restart', or to be more specific, the date/time the statistics for (all, the specific) DMV was reset.

Since it would be quite important to know last reset when looking at the statistics, I want to make absolutely sure the date/time is accurate and shown.

Question: How can you get the most accurate date/time of when a/all DMV statistic was reset?

Thanks!
-D

Comment: Sometimes need to be better about knowing the correct key-words to search for, duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036824/find-out-how-long-the-sql-server-service-has-been-running-from-t-sql

Comment: **See Also**: [Find Last Restart of SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2501/find-last-restart-of-sql-server/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a prior question (different key words), I ended up using this approach. As always, up to the individual what would be 'best' for them!

SELECT create_date 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'tempdb'

source: [Find out how long the sql server service has been running, from t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036824/find-out-how-long-the-sql-server-service-has-been-running-from-t-sql)

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT sqlserver_start_time FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work but you have to know the service name also its only available with R2 and later

```
SELECT last_startup_time 
FROM   sys.dm_server_services 
WHERE  servicename = "Your Service name"
```

Although this won't be totally accurate since you can also reset the DB specific views via a DB detach or a DB close.

Also there are [two views that can be reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/362243/119477) on a live db `sys.dm_os_latch_stats` and `sys.dm_os_wait_stats`

Answer (score 0):

> There are many ways to check when was SQL server restarted last time.
>
> Below mentioned  SQL queries can be used to quickly find out the
>   server restart date time.

```
 SELECT sqlserver_start_time FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info;  



SELECT login_time FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = 1;  



 select start_time from sys.traces where is_default = 1  ;



 SELECT crdate FROM sysdatabases WHERE name='tempdb'  ;



 SELECT create_date FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'tempdb' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various way to find out SQL Server reboot time. Following are the codes which return the server re-boot date:

```
SELECT sqlserver_start_time FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info;  
SELECT login_time FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = 1; 
SELECT start_time from sys.traces where is_default = 1;
SELECT crdate FROM sysdatabases WHERE name='tempdb';
SELECT create_date FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'tempdb';
```